# OpenTok-java-sdk issue Create SessionId throwing exception

Tags: java, maven, opentok, tokbox

I am working on maven and spring.
  I have created simple class having main method,
  to create the OpenTok SessionId but getting exception as follows

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient$BoundRequestBuilder.setParameters(Lcom/ning/http/client/FluentStringsMap;)Lcom/ning/http/client/AsyncHttpClient$BoundRequestBuilder;
>     at com.opentok.util.HttpClient.createSession(HttpClient.java:48)    at
>   com.opentok.OpenTok.createSession(OpenTok.java:252)   at
>   com.opentok.OpenTok.createSession(OpenTok.java:306)   at
>   webapp.test.com.OpenToks.main(OpenTokProg.java:28)

My code is inside main method

```
  OpenTok opentok = new OpenTok(API_KEY,API_SECRET);
  String sessionId = opentok.createSession().getSessionId();
```

I having tried following steps -- got from "forums.tokbox.com/supported-server-api/exception-while-getting-session-object-in-java-t46638#p60778"

1) Make sure that you successfully build path for java server sdk.
--> used in pom.xml

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tokbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentok-server-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

2) Try using hard coded API key and secret key (for testing purpose)at the time you making object of Opentok.
--> tried again same error

3) Make sure you have an access to Opentok server, run a diagnose over this link.
http://tokbox.com/tools/connectivity/
--> getting Message: Successful for all connections

Please help

Answer (score 0):

The version of `AsyncHttpClient` that was used for compiling `com.opentok.util.HttpClient` (probably 1.8) is different from the one that's provided at runtime (probably 1.9).

Between those versions, the `setParameters` method was renamed into `setFormParameters`.

You have to find out where this clash comes from and resolve it. Use `mvn dependency:tree` to figure out which library depends on which.

Comment: I have added this dependency and now it working fine <dependency>
   <groupId>com.ning</groupId>
   <artifactId>async-http-client</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.1</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Honestly, you'd better figure out which component drags you down with such an old version, and try to upgrade it. AHC 1.9 as tons of improvements such as security fixes. Then, please validate the answer.

Comment: Frankly i don't know how to customize this lib, i just want to use it in my app. And it sometimes causes OpenTokException.